# How to define an AWS ELB in Ansible with a listener that has a range of ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I'm creating an AWS ELB that will sit in front of two EC2 instances using Ansible. This ELB will listen on the usual SSH port and a range between 6000 and 6100.

```
- name: Create ELB for web servers
  local_action:
    module: ec2_elb_lb
    name: "{{ elb_web }}"
    state: present
    zones: "{{ availability_zones }}"
    tags:
      Name: "{{ elb_web }}"
    listeners:
      - protocol: http
        load_balancer_port: 80
        instance_port: 80
        proxy_protocol: True
      - protocol: tcp
        from_port????
    cross_az_load_balancing: "yes"
    security_group_names: "{{ security_group_web }}"
    wait: yes
  register: elb_web_result
  until: "elb_web_result.module_stderr is not defined"
  retries: 2
  delay: 1
```

How to define an AWS ELB in Ansible with a listener that has a range of ports instead of port by port? Or maybe even better, how to I define that anything coming from a specific security group should be listened to and sent to the instances?

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK Amazon ELB doesn't support listening on a range of ports. You must specify one port for one listener. So this is not actually an ansible question.

Comment: Sorry I was confused by the question, you will have to define a security group for above port range and then attach it to ELB you cannot a define a port range listeners for ELB and if you want them then you have to do it one by one.

Comment: Yes, I guess it is the only way. :( Would you do it with something like with_items?

Comment: Is there a way to iterate the listeners in the ec2_elb_lb task? I tried with_items but it seems to only keep the last listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very odd task indeed, but if you really do want to create a load balancer with such a huge port range, you can use this trick:

```
- set_fact:
    listener:
      protocol: tcp
      load_balancer_port: "{{item}}"
      instance_port: "{{item}}"
  with_sequence: start=6000 end=6100
  register: listeners_range

- set_fact:
    listeners_range: "{{ listeners_range.results | map(attribute='ansible_facts.listener') | list }}"

- debug: var=listeners_range
```

This will make variable `listeners_range` with list of items ranged 6000-6100:

```
protocol: tcp
load_balancer_port: "{{item}}"
instance_port: "{{item}}"
```

So you can call `ec2_elb_lb` and specify `listeners: "{{listeners_range}}"`